# Attacked by a .vbs File

Tags: virus, virus-scanning, adsutil.vbs

I am attacked by a .vbs file which turns the files on **only removable hard drive** into shortcuts(.lnk)
Tried the attrib command from command prompt but it recovers file just for few seconds and then again all files turns into shortcuts.

I am having some very important data on my removable hard drive.

Comment: There's really not much we can do.  I'd recommend not executing scripts that you don't fully understand, and investing in some good antivirus.

Comment: apologies for the mistakes.please comment only if you have solutions

Comment: @JohnSaunders:  *Granted*, but there's a nicer way to phrase it.

Comment: @Makoto: what is the nicer way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it keeps happening, try ending wscript.exe from command prompt - sounds like the script is still running.